# Why aren't the methods generated by has_and_belongs_to_many bidirectional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have...

**app/models/report.rb:**

```
has_and_belongs_to :standards
```

**app/models/standard.rb:**

```
has_and_belongs_to :reports
```

**db/schema.rb:**

```
create_table "reports_standards", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "report_id"
  t.integer "standard_id"
end
```

When I log into rails console, all seems OK initially...

```
> @report = Report.create :name => "foo"
 => #<Report id: 2, name: "foo", created_at: "2013-02-21 03:10:06", updated_at: "2013-02-21 03:10:06"> 
> @standard = @report.standards.build :name => "bar"
 => #<Standard id: nil, name: "bar", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
> @report.standards
 => [#<Standard id: nil, name: "bar", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

...but then it turns strange...

```
> @standard.reports
 => []
```

Isn't it meant to be:

```
> @standard.reports
 => [#<Report id: 2, name: "foo", created_at: "2013-02-21 03:10:06", updated_at: "2013-02-21 03:10:06">]
```

Why isn't it? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are running `@report.standards.build :name => "bar"` which only builds the record and not create it in the database. if you change build to create, you should be able to see the associations.